# How do I disconnect a Scala Remote Actor?

Tags: scala, actor, disconnect

In scala it is very easy to make a connection to a remote actor, but the documentation does not tell me anything about disconnecting. Simply throwing away the reference does not work, because remote actors are actors, so these won't be collected until stopped. So how do I disconnect?

This does not Terminate after exit:

```
import actors.{DaemonActor,remote}
import remote.{RemoteActor,Node}

object SimpleClient{
    val messageHandler = new DaemonActor{
        def act{
            loop{
                react{
                    case message:String =>
                        println("got message: " + message)
                    case _ =>
                }
            }
        }
        start
    }

    def main(args:Array[String]){
        val server = RemoteActor.select(Node("localhost",9999),'server)
        server.send('Connect,messageHandler)

        var exit = false
        while(!exit){
            val message = Console.readLine
            if(message == "exit" || message == "quit") {
                exit = true
                server ! 'Disconnect
            }
            else
                server ! message
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Server:

```
import actors.{Actor,OutputChannel}
import actors.remote.RemoteActor

object Server extends Actor{
    val clients = new collection.mutable.HashSet[OutputChannel[Any]]
    def act{
        loop{
            react{
                case 'Connect =>
                    clients += sender
                case 'Disconnect =>
                    clients -= sender
                case message:String =>
                    for(client <- clients)
                        client ! message
            }
        }
    }

    def main(args:Array[String]){
        start
        RemoteActor.alive(9999)
        RemoteActor.register('server,this)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working version of your source, with pertinent changes commented inline:

```
import actors.{DaemonActor,remote}
import remote.{RemoteActor,Node}

case class Send(message: String)
case object Disconnect

object SimpleClient{
    val messageHandler = new DaemonActor{

       def act{
          // keep the reference to the proxy inside the client-side actor
          val server = RemoteActor.select(Node("localhost",9999),'server)
          server ! 'Connect
          loop{
             react{
                case message:String =>
                   println("got message: " + message)
                case Send(message) => server ! message
                case Disconnect => { 
                   // disconnect and exit the client-side actor
                   server ! 'Disconnect //'
                   exit
                }
                case _ =>
              }
          }
      }
      start
   }

   def main(args:Array[String]){
      var exit = false
      while(!exit){
         val message = Console.readLine
         if(message == "exit" || message == "quit") {
            exit = true
            // tell the client-side actor to exit
            messageHandler ! Disconnect
         } else {
            messageHandler ! Send(message)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: cool that works, thank you. I have seen that you moved the server inside of the Message handler, but why does this behave different from having the server saved in the block of the main loop?

Answer (score 3):

[Disclaimer: I'm PO of Akka]

May I suggest taking a look at Akka, which was built with Remote Actors in mind from day 1?
www.akka.io

Comment: Thanks for that Aaron, I try to be clear on my affiliations :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not really clear enough about what problem you think you are experiencing. Actors do **not** "connect" to each other (like a socket). You send an actor a message because you have a reference to it (or a proxy, in the case of remote actors).

Having such a reference does not prevent the actor (either actor) from shutting down. If there are no longer any references to an actor and it is not running, there is nothing to stop it being garbage-collected

Comment: Thats the point. The remote actor is still running. The actors on the server have to keep running, thats the job of the server, and so do the remote actors on the client side. These proxies keep my program from shutting down correctly.

Comment: @Arne - I'm afraid it's just not clear enough what the issue is. Why can't you just `exit` the actors you want to stop?

Comment: There is one actor on the server that receives connections of clients. You can call him the welcome actor. This actor must not stop, because is is the same actor for all clients. I can't kill it only because one client wants to shut down its JVM. I only want to kill the remote instance of this actor

Comment: @Arne On the client side, you should have at least two actors: the remote proxy created with `select` and a client actor that sends messages to the proxy.  Assuming only the client actor has a reference to the remote proxy, terminating the client (with its `exit` method) will allow your client-side JVM to terminate.

Comment: Ok now I have posted my sourcecode. It does not terminate, and the reference to the proxy is definitely already gone.

Answer (score 2):

The `Reactor` trait defines `protected[actors] def exit(): Nothing` which the actor can call itself upon reception of a message telling it to do so.

```
sealed trait Msg
case object Apoptosis extends Msg
// ... more messages


class RRActor extends Reactor[Msg] {
  def act =  loop {
    react {
      // ... Whatever messages the actor handles
      case Apoptosis => this.exit
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: I have not tested this ever with remote actors.

Comment: It does not *have* to be told to `exit`! It can decide for itself to `exit` whenever it wants to

Comment: Do they exit if you use loop? How and why does it decide to exit? My usage of actors has been limited and this trick is what I use.